# Android app lock app return after authentication

Tags: android, locking, applocker

I'm trying to build an app lock application. I have created a service to monitor current running apps. And checking which app is opened, I redirects to my app lock.

When I open the app, it is guided to lock app. Till that it's ok. After successful authentication, I want to continue with my opened app. How can I achieve that?

I have used below codes to open app lock from the locked app.

```
      Intent i = new Intent(ServiceClass.this, AppLockActivity.class);              
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(i);
```

After successful authentication, I want to continue with my app, without any interaction from the app lock. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can call `finish()` to kill your `AppLockActivity`

Comment: it only finishes the activity

Comment: @Hari Than what you want to do?

Comment: i want to finish close the locker app and resume with the base app

Comment: @Hari try to use `finishAffinity();` instead of `finish()`